# Calculate % of number in Scala programming

Tags: xcode, scala, syntax, mathematical-optimization, development-environment

How to do 50% of 120 in scala code..need proper syntax ,& runnable code for same.

Eg :

```
int k = (int)(120*(50.0f/100.0f));
```

This is in java need scala code for same.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why it didn't work? - Also, what would be the input? an `Int` between `0` and `100`? What should the program do if the input is wrong? - What would be the output? Another `Int`? How should we approximate the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be:

```scala
(120*(50.0f/100.0f)).toInt
```

Comment: def loyaltyCardPressed(): Unit = {
    // TODO
    // go through items in store and get the values, apply the sale to those values
    // for loop to apply to useLoyality
    for ((x, y) <- itemInStore) {
      y.useLoyalty()
    }

  // var addMod: Double = 0.0
   // for (z <- itemsInCart()){
   // addMod += z.price()
   // }
  }